# Python init file name convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I started a new Python project and I want to have a good structure from the beginning. I'm reading some convention Python guides but I don't find any info about how the main script must be named. Is there any rules for this? Is there any other kind of convention for folders or text files inside the project (like readme files)?

By the way, I'm programming a client-server app so there is no way for this to become a package (at least in the way a think a package is).

Comment: What framework? Also from what I've seen most people just use main.py or something generic.

Comment: No framework at the moment. Is not a web app.

Comment: For something official see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions.

Comment: `Is not a web app.`, you can use something like twisted(which is a framework) to develop client-server apps. Just pointing out that not all frameworks are for webapps.

Comment: Yes, I checked that before post but I didn't find anything related. I think that I'm going to check some popular project to see if the use any convention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such rule exists for python main script which starts your application. There are coding [guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (PEP8) which you can follow to keep your code clean though.

You can check existing python applications which are easily available. May be open source/free software projects e.g yum (on rpm based distros) command, lots of [python apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software#Applications) (you can checkout them from publicly available source code management systems e.g git repo) etc. You can check basic principles they follow. But there are no constraints as such.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to package your application to allow a  ZIP file containing it or its directory to be passed as an argument to the python interpreter to run the application, name your main script `__main__.py`. If you don't care about being able to do this (and most python applications do not), name it whatever you want.